# How to get the recordset data from Word VBA to excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm new to VBA, for part of a requirement I need to get the data from SQL table to Excel sheet using Word macro. I tried to

1. Connect to SQL using ADODB connection and created & set an object for recordset
2. I have created and set the necessary excel objects like Excel.Application, Excel.WorkBook and Excel.WorkSheet
   But I'm stuck with how to get the data from recordset into Excel sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a guide on the microsoft website:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/transfer-excel-data-from-ado-recordset

This part is probably the key bit you need (but you also may need the part before to process date values and other more complex data types:

```
' Transpose and Copy the array to the worksheet,
        ' starting in cell A2
        xlWs.Cells(2, 1).Resize(recCount, fldCount).Value = _
            TransposeDim(recArray)
```